# How to detect and change shape in Java OpenGL

Tags: java, swing, opengl, jogl

I drew some shapes using OpenGL, here is the code:

### The drawing methods:

```
private void drawRectangle(GL2 gl, double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3, double y3, double x4, double y4) {
        gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_LINE_LOOP);
        gl.glVertex2d(x1, y1);
        gl.glVertex2d(x2, y2);
        gl.glVertex2d(x3, y3);
        gl.glVertex2d(x4, y4);
        gl.glEnd();
    }
```

```
private void drawCircle(GL2 gl, double centerX, double centerY, double radius) {
        gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_LINE_STRIP);
         for (double i = 0; i < 360; i++) {
             double radian = i * Math.PI / 180;
             double x = radius * Math.cos(radian) + centerX;
             double y = radius * Math.sin(radian) + centerY;

             gl.glVertex2d(x, y);
         }
         gl.glEnd();
    }
```

I drew some circles and rectangles, here is the display method:

```
public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        final GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
        gl.glColor3f(1f, 1f, 1f);
        
        drawCircle(gl, 0.7, 0.2, 0.1);
        drawCircle(gl, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3);
        drawRectangle(gl, -0.5, -0.5, 0, -0.5, 0, 0, -0.5, 0);
    }
```

The displayed result:
[image]

I want to fill the shape with a color when I click on it. (static color for all clicks, red for example)

```
class Color {
    public double c1, c2, c3;

    public Color(double c1, double c2, double c3) {
        super();
        this.c1 = c1;
        this.c2 = c2;
        this.c3 = c3;
    }
}
```

So I want to know 2 things:
1- how can I fill the shape with a color?
2- how to fill the shape when I click on it?

I'm using `javax.swing.JFrame` to show the canvas, but there is no problem if there is a way using anything else such as JavaFX or AWT or something else.

---

### The main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        final GLProfile profile = GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL2);
        GLCapabilities capabilities = new GLCapabilities(profile);
        final GLCanvas glcanvas = new GLCanvas(capabilities);
        Driver driver = new Driver();
        glcanvas.addGLEventListener(driver);
        glcanvas.setSize(400, 400);

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().add(glcanvas);
        frame.setSize(frame.getContentPane().getPreferredSize());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Comment: If you want to fill the shape with a color, you must use one of the [Triangle primitives](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Triangle_primitives) instead of `GL2.GL_LINE_LOOP`

Comment: I used `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN` in both `drawCircle` and `drawRectangle` methods, and it works. Thanks

Comment: Why is this tagged javafx?

Comment: @James_D I'm using `javax.swing.JFrame` to show the JOGL canvas, but there is no problem if there is a way using anything else such as JavaFX or AWT or something else.

Comment: *"I'm using `javax.swing.JFrame`"*. But that has nothing to do with JavaFX.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fill the shape with a color, you must use one of the [Triangle primitives](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Triangle_primitives) instead of `GL2.GL_LINE_LOOP`. e.g.: `GL2.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN`:

```java
gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
gl.glVertex2d(x1, y1);
gl.glVertex2d(x2, y2);
gl.glVertex2d(x3, y3);
gl.glVertex2d(x4, y4);
gl.glEnd();
```

```java
gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
for (double i = 0; i < 360; i++) {
    double radian = i * Math.PI / 180;
    double x = radius * Math.cos(radian) + centerX;
    double y = radius * Math.sin(radian) + centerY;
    gl.glVertex2d(x, y);
}
gl.glEnd();
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked.

now the big problem is how to fill the shape when I click on it

Comment: @ObadaJaras You need to use something called picking.

Comment: Maybe this example can help you: https://jogamp.org/cgit/jogl-demos.git/tree/src/demos/misc/Picking.java